# Errors when trying NetSuite's Restlet interface: datain is null

Tags: netsuite

I'm trying out Restlets for the first time and I am having trouble returning any data.

I've built a basic restlet and deployed it in NetSuite. The code is as follows:

```
function getRESTlet(dataIn) {   
     return nlapiLoadRecord(dataIn.recordtype, dataIn.id); // e.g recordtype="customer", id="769"
}
```

Using Chromes' REST Console application I've set up the following:

```
Request URI: https://rest.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=123&deploy=1&recordtype=customer&id=2409
Request Headers: NLAuth nlauth_account=123456,nlauth_email=email@emailaddy.com,nlauth_signature=password
```

Running it as a `GET` operation I return the following error:

```
error code: JS_EXCEPTION
error message:type
```

Followed by the following email:

```
Date & Time: 8/19/2013 2:48 pm
Execution Time: 0.06s
Script Usage: 0
Script: getRecord
Type: RESTlet
Function: getRESTlet
Error: SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT
type
Stack Trace: getRESTlet(getCustomer.js:14)
restletwrapper(null$lib:3)
```

The customer record exists, the RestLet code is from the NetSuite help system, and I get an error email when the script fails so I know the deployment URL is good.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

--EDIT--

Changing my function signature to `function getRESTlet(type,dataIn)` resolves the type error, although now I get:

```
error code: UNEXPECTED_ERROR
error message:TypeError: Cannot read property "recordtype" from undefined (getCustomer.js#14)
```

I've also removed `customer` and `id` from the `request URI` and instead listed them in the `Request Payload` section of REST Console.

--Edit 2--

adding `nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'JSON.stringify(datain) is:', JSON.stringify(datain));` to the function is returning blank for the log entry. It appears that datain is null....

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue that was resolved once I set the request header content-type to application/json.

The default content-type is text/plain which passes a stringified JSON object to the function and expects a string to be returned.

If you set the content-type to application/json or application/xml the 'datain' parameter will come in as a javascript object.

From the NetSuite Docs:

> **If users specify a content type other than JSON or TEXT, a 415 error
>   is returned with the following message:**
>
> Invalid content type. You can
>   only use application/json, application/xml or text/plain with
>   RESTlets.
>
> **If users provide data in a format different from specified
>   type, the following error is returned with one of the following
>   messages:**
>
> Error code = INVALID_RETURN_DATA_FORMAT Error message =
>   Invalid data format. You should return TEXT. Error message = Invalid
>   data format. You should return a JavaScript object.

Comment: Note - The content type in RESTlets is controlled by the client request header `Content-Type`, not the `Accepts` header as I was expecting, or by setting a content type in the response. Content-type of the response is always the same as the request, apparently. Very odd.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the error of

> Error code = INVALID_RETURN_DATA_FORMAT Error message =
>   Invalid data format. You should return TEXT. Error message = Invalid
>   data format. You should return a JavaScript object.

You can supply a Content-type to the get specified get request of 'json'. Documentation would seem to indicate that you should specify "accepts" json, but for me only the content-type on a get made the request work.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error: SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT when trying to submit a transform record type that I had specified in camel case rather that all lower case... took me a day to work that out :(

Answer (score -2):

changing the function to:

```
function getRESTlet(datain) {   
     return nlapiLoadRecord(datain.recordtype, datain.id); // e.g recordtype="customer", id="769"
}
```

resolves the issue. I thought I had tried without camelCase, but alas I did not.

So moral of the story is: **datain is case sensitive!**

Comment: The case-sensitivity of "datain" does not make any sense. Whatever you use for the parameter name will be the name given to the request payload. It will be case-sensitive, but it does not have to be a specific name (e.g. datain). I just created a test script where my function is `getRESTlet(testingParam)`. Everything works as expected. My payload is transferred into the properties of testingParam. Accessing it by testingparam or any other name gives an error as expected. I don't even see how your last sample works, unless NetSuite defines its own dataIn variable behind the scenes.

Comment: It looks to me that in your EDIT 2 you are trying to log `datain` but your parameter name was still `dataIn` at this point, so no `datain` variable would exist.

Comment: So at the end, there's no answer to this thread and I have the exact same problem ...

Comment: there was a resolution, I was calling datain incorrectly. feel free to post a new question and link back here. I'll take a look at my earliest opportunity, as will others. likewise post in the netsuite users group and someone from their support team may respond. or alternatively contact their support team.

Comment: So when you use the the datain like you do, it works ? Because I just had the same problem than you and `datain` was giving as a string so I had to parse the JSON to give back a json file accessible in my code.

Comment: It works: `if (datain.recordtype == 'salesorder') {
        rec = nlapiLoadRecord(datain.recordtype, datain.id); ... }` each param in your request equates to an object inside of datain. So if my request is `&recordtype=salesorder&id=101` in the code above I would load a sales order with the internal ID of 101 into the rec variable.